# $G = G(p_1) \times G(p_2) \times \cdots \times G(p_k)$ and $|G(p_i)| = p_i ^{n_i}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

After the proof of this lemma:

> Let $G$ be a finite Abelian group of order $p^nm$, where $p$ is a prime that
> does not divide $m$. Then $G = H \times K$, where $H = \{x \in G \mid x^{p^n}= e\}$
> and $K = \{x \in  G \mid x^m = e\}$. Moreover, $|H| = p^n$.

They tell me the following:

> Given an Abelian group $G$ with $|G|= p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2} \cdots p_k^{n_k}$, where the
> $p’s$ are distinct primes, we let $G(p_i)$ denote the set $\{x \in G \mid x^{{p_i}^{n_i}} = e\}$. It then follows immediately from Lemma 1 and induction that $G = G(p_1) \times G(p_2) \times\cdots \times G(p_k)$ and $|G(p_i)| = p_i ^{n_i}$.

My problem is that I don't really know how to do this induction. Any hint please?

I know this question is not very elaborate. But I have had quite a bit of difficulty solving group problems using induction. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Who are you referring to when you say, "they"? The author(s) of a textbook? Please share. What's the first thing you struggle with in the induction?

Comment: Should $H$ be "$x^{p^n}=e$" rather than $x^pn$, which doesn't really make sense?

Comment: Do induction on $k$. If $k=2$, the lemma gives it to you. Otherwise, you get $G=H\times K$ with $H$ of order $p_1^{n_1}$, and $K$ of order $p_2^{n_2}\cdots p_l^{n_k}$. Then apply the induction hypothesis to $K$.

Comment: @Shaun I mean the book. On the other hand, I didn't know exactly what to do induction...

Comment: Yes, but *which* book? Arturo Magidin's comment is a good hint. Apply the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: @Shaun The book is a recommendation you made me. "Contemporary abstract algebra" by gallian. And yes, the hint has been very helpful to me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The base case $k=1$ is immediate,  by Lagrange.

If we assume the result for given  $k $, then the result  for  $k+1$ follows immediately from the lemma, since $|G|=p_{k+1}^{n_{k+1}}m $, where $p_{k+1}\not|m $.